# Calling a method's variablename from class A into Class B

Tags: python, class

I have been searching an answer to my question but could not hit the related answer.

Basically i am trying to call a variable from a Class A thats actually GUI to another Class B my code goes like this:

```
class CLASSA(wx.Frame):
    def Method(self):
        self.Var = anyvalue

import CLASSA
class CLASSB():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Var = CLASSA().Method.Var
```

i have tried as above but its not working out. Isn't it possible to carry out as mentioned ?

Answer (score 2):

At the very least, you need to actually *call* `CLASSA.Method` first:

```
class CLASSB():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Var = CLASSA().Method().Var
```

in order for the `Var` attribute of the `CLASSA` object to be initialized.

You do not give enough detail to know if `Method` is necessary. You could, for instance, simply initialize `Var` in `CLASSA.__init__`.

```
# With recommended capitalization
class A(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = any value

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        sef.var = A().var
```

It's also possible that `B` should be a subclass of `A`, in which case `B` simply inherits `var` from `A`:

```
>>> class B(A):
...    pass

>>> print B().var
anyvalue
```

Comment: The method of class A isnot callable

Comment: _windows_.Frame_swiginit(self,_windows_.new_Frame(*args, **kwargs))
TypeError: Required argument 'parent' (pos 1) not found

Comment: That's because you aren't instantiating `CLASSA` properly. You derive from `wx.Frame` without overriding `__init__`, so it needs the same arguments that `wx.Frame()` would expect.